# Servo controlled valve

Tags: otherservos, valve

I am trying to build a servo-controlled water valve.  Max pressure 150 psi , valve size 1/2".

Can anyone recommend a suitable 1/4-turn valve, either ceramic, ball valve, or anything else that is *easy* to turn, even under pressure? It must require very little torque to turn, so a standard servo can rotate it with a small lever attached.

Comment: What's your application?  I'm not sure something like an RC servo is the right solution here.  Are you familiar with solenoid valves?

Comment: Application is controlling water flow, so a solenoid (on/off only) is not suitable.  I need to be able to partially open/close the valve to allow various flow rates.  Thanks!

Comment: There are commercial units available, very expensive.  I  am trying to build my own for a low cost application.

Comment: It looks like what i want is called a 'proportional valve' as per http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60370/variable-liquid-flow-rate-control

Comment: If you have feedback you may be able to modulate (e.g. PWM) an on-off valve to get the flow you need...

Comment: This looks like a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), so I'm not sure that it would be valid for any SE site.

Comment: So we can't ask for help sourcing parts for our projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty common to take a simple and cheap solenoid valve and use a PWM at the input

TI  has a pretty nice driver (DRV102) which uses a analog input and provides enough power to switch the most valves. I don't even need a MCU, just a variable resistor is enought
Then just take a cheap valve and the job is done

Comment: Very interesting. Does the liquid exit the line in visible pulses?

Comment: The used PWM is about 24kHz
You cannot see any pulses
the piston in the valve is just kept in a middle position proportinal to the duty cycle of the pwm

Comment: This is exactly the info i was looking for.  I did not know solenoid valves could use PWM to partially open.  I assumed the valve would pulse open and closed, causing choppy water output.  Thank you!